# I need to regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need two regular expression. 
1) Any characters followed by a comma followed by any characters followed by a comma followed by any characters.

Currently I have:

```
/(.*,.*,.*)/
```

2) Any characters followed by a comma followed by any characters so long as they are not a comma.

Currently I have:

```
/(.*,.*[^,]+.*)/
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1.) I recommend regexr.com to test your Regex and 2.) Add some example strings of what should and should not match each pattern

Comment: I read and don't understand question

Comment: _Any characters followed by a comma_ is a vague description. Since regex for `Any character` will consume `comma`

Answer (score 1):

For your first Regex you could really just use Javascript built in `string.split(",");` Which would return an array of strings. From there run a check for `array.length >= 3` and you'll know the string matched you pattern. That being said f there are commas in the characters after that second required comma you could have issues depending on what you are expecting.

The second Regex could be verified using `string.split(",")` as well. Your second check would just be `array.length === 2`

The full code would be something like this

```
function verify(str) {
    var arr = str.split(",");
    if (arr.length < 2)
        return "Invalid string provided";

    if (arr.length === 2)
        return arr[0] + arr[1];

    return join(arr);
}

verify("some,crazy,comma delimited voodoo");
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first regular expression, `/(.*,.*,.*)/`, you have what you're looking for.  Note that "any character" includes commas, so really this only guarantees that there will be at *least* 2 commas.

For the second, `/(.*,.*[^,]+.*)/`, that's not quite right.  "Any characters followed by a comma followed by any characters so long as they are not a comma" would be `/(.*,[^,]*)/`.  However again, consider that "any characters" includes commas, so it is somewhat meaningless.

Perhaps you mean something more like `/([^,]*,[^,]*)/`?  This is any text with precisely one comma.  You can repeat the pattern by adding a second `,[^,]*` as you wish, for example `/([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*)/` is for precisely two commas.

If you wish to match any number of items separated by commas, try `/([^,]+,?)/g` to match each individual list item.

If you also require that there is text between commas, use + instead of *.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know the utility of your regular expressions but in the linux grep command this will work:

grep '?,?,?'

grep '?,*[^,]'